# How do you set terminal options like t_Co in neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lua

When I put into my `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`

```
vim.opt.t_Co = 256
```

I get

> E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_meta.lua:659: Not a valid option name: t_Co

But [there is an option in vim called `t_Co`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15375992/124486). This is a port from my vimrc line,

```
set t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the configuration file format these are a no-op in VIM Script and an error in the Lua API. From `:he t_xx`

> `t_xx termcap-options t_AB t_Sb t_vb t_SI` Nvim does not have special `t_XX` options nor `<t_XX> keycodes` to configure terminal capabilities. Instead Nvim treats the terminal as any other UI, e.g. `guicursor` sets the terminal cursor style if possible.