# Prevent Neovim from setting Application Cursor Keys Mode [PuTTY]

Tags: neovim

I’m using `nvim` within a `PuTTY` terminal and I’m having trouble with the `Arrow Keys` and the `Ctrl + Arrow keys`. Both keys generate identical character sequences, leading to some complications.

While I was able to address this in `vim` by setting `t_ks` and `t_ke` to empty, it appears that these options aren't available in `nvim` according to [link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37190/49269).

The `application cursor keys mode` in `PuTTY`'s settings cannot be disabled due to its interference with navigation in other tools like `man`, `ranger`, `mc`, `htop`, etc.

Interestingly enough, the `Ctrl + Arrow keys` work perfectly when I use `nvim` inside `tmux`.

I'm under the impression that a change in the terminal settings could be necessary.

So, I would like to know how I can prevent Neovim from starting in `application cursor key mode` when operating inside `PuTTY`.

### Configs:

- `Terminal > Features > Disable application cursor keys mode` is unchecked.
- `Terminal > Keyboard > Shift/Ctrl/Alt with the arrow keys` set to `xterm-style-bitmap`

##### $ cat /usr/share/doc/tmux/example_tmux.conf:

```python
# Change the default $TERM to tmux-256color
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```